# Calculate mode for multiple columns within multiple dataframes and store

Tags: r, loops, mode

My limited mental capacity means I am really struggling to perform the following task in R, any advice would be gratefully received!

I have 100 dataframes currently stored as a list (my.dfs). Within each dataframe there are six columns (a,b,c,d,e,f). The row number varies between dataframes (80-150), but I think this is irrelevant. All columns are numeric.

I would like to calculate the mode for column a in dataframe 1, then dataframe 2,3,4... through to dataframe 100, and store the results in a new vector (a.mode). So a.mode should have 100 mode values, each from one of the dataframes. I then wish to repeat this for columns b,c,d,e,f which can each have their own vector (b.mode, c.mode, etc).

My problem is that calculating mode in R does not appear to be straightforward. I use the package (modeest) and the command:

```
mlv(column.here, method="mfv")
```

So my code currently looks like this:

```
library(modeest)
my.dfs
a.mode<-NULL

for( j in my.dfs){
a.mode<-c(a.mode, mlv(j[,"column.a"], method="mfv"))
}
```

This however gives a jumble of outputs that is not correct.

similarly I have tried:

```
for( j in my.dfs){
a.mode<-c(a.mode, mlv(j$column.a, method="mfv"))
}
```

But I get the error command:

```
Error in j$column.a : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I have additionally tried making my list into 100 separate dataframes to see if running a loop on separate dataframes would be more effective. However, I haven't got beyond separating my list into 100 dataframes:

```
t<-1:100
for (q in 1:length(t)){
assign(paste("metric.data", t[q], sep=""), data.frame(subset(my.dfs[[q]])))
}
```

I don't know how I might additionally run a loop through all 100 dataframes that calculates mode for column.a within each dataframe and stores them in a vector (a.mode), and then repeat this for column.b, column.c etc as described above.

Any ideas and code would be fantastic

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code:

1. It should be `for (j in 1:my.dfs) {...}` otherwise the loop will loop only once since `j` doesn't take all the values between `1` and `my.dfs`.
2. What is `my.dfs` after all? It doesn't look like you're assigning anything at all to it? If you want the loop to have as many runs as there are data frames in your list `my.dfs` (assuming it is a list of dfs) you should try `runs <- length(my.dfs)` and `for (j in 1:runs) {...}`.
3. Your use of `j` is very likely the cause of the error message here. It looks like you're trying to use j as a placeholder for the elements in `my.dfs` but it doesn't work like that. Instead you should do: `mlv(my.dfs[[j]],method="mfv")`. Again, the error message tells you that `j` is an atomic vector. It doesn't contain your data frames. As far as I can interpret that correctly, looking at your code, it shouldn't even contain an atomic vector but a list instead (again, given the assumption that `my.dfs` is a list of dfs).
4. There are a few other issues and I recommend, next time you ask a question, please make sure your code is correct and/or not just pseudo code since it makes your question very confusing.

IF I correctly interpret the actual question behind your code, your problem is that the output of `mlv` is actually a list and not a single value. If you want the single value, you can access it like this:

```
my.data <- matrix(rnorm(1:10,5),byrow=F,nrow=10,ncol=5) # create example data
list.of.modes <- apply(my.data,2,mlv,method="mfv") # get the mode
vector.of.modes <- NULL # create the vector we want
for (i in 1:length(list.of.modes)) {
  vector.of.modes[i] <- list.of.modes[[i]]$M #<---This is the interesting line
}
```

This should work similarly for data frames and with your example. You'll have to adapt it though, since the code I posted only goes as far as necessary to explain the principle idea behind it.